# Compilation problem "undefined reference to "

Tags: fortran

I get the following error when trying to compile my code

```
hdf5.o: In function `hdf5_module_mp_readhdf5_':
hdf5.F:(.text+0x322e): undefined reference to `courant_'
```

The main code is channel.f (there are others which don't play a role in this problem), which contains a function called "courant"

```
      MODULE channel_module
      USE shared_module
      USE solvers_module
      USE les_module
      USE hdf5_module

      CONTAINS
      .....
      SUBROUTINE COURANT
      ..
      END SUBROUTINE COURANT
      .....
      END MODULE channel_module
```

And the problem is in hdf5.f, where there's another function which calls "courant"

```
      MODULE hdf5_module
      USE shared_module
      USE mpi_module

      CONTAINS 
      .....
      subroutine ReadHDF5
      ...
      CALL COURANT
      ...
      end subroutine ReadHDF5

      END MODULE hdf5_module
```

This is the makefile:

```
# This is the makefile 

COMPILER = ifort

USEROPTS = -O3 -fpp -mcmodel=large
FCOMP = -fpic -i_dynamic -mcmodel=large
LINK = -fpic -i_dynamic -mcmodel=large8.15-parallel

LINKDIR = -L/apps/fftw/2.1.5-double/lib -L/apps/hdf5/1.8.15/parallel/lib

INCLUDEDIR = -I/apps/fftw/2.1.5-double/include -I/apps/hdf5/1.8.15/parallel/include

PARALLEL = TRUE

LES = TRUE

NETCDF = FALSE
HDF5 = TRUE

NEWTON = FALSE

# Option to run different flavors (basic, ensemble, etc.)
ENSEM = FALSE
BATCH = FALSE
# **********    END of user definitions ************

ifeq ($(ARCH),ifort)
COMPILER = ifort
USEROPTS = -O3 -fpp
else ifeq ($(ARCH),gfortran)
COMPILER = gfortran
USEROPTS = -O3 -cpp
endif

ifeq ($(LES),TRUE)
LES_o = les.o
else
LES_o = no_les.o
endif

ALL2ALL=1

ifeq ($(PARALLEL),TRUE)
COMPILER = mpif90 
MPI = mpi.o
MPIF = mpi.alltoall$(ALL2ALL).F
ifeq ($(HDF5),TRUE)
HDF5_o = hdf5.o 
COMPILER = h5pfc
HDF5OPTS=-DHDF5
endif
ifeq ($(NEWTON),TRUE)
NEWTONOPTS=-DNEWTON
endif
else
ifeq ($(HDF5),TRUE)
HDF5_o = hdf5s.o 
COMPILER = h5pfc
HDF5OPTS=-DHDF5
endif
MPI = mpi_serial.o
endif

MAIN = diablo.f
HEADER = header
ENSEM_HOOKS = dummy_code/ensem_dummy.f
BATCH_HOOKS = dummy_code/batch_dummy.f
HOOKS = batch_hooks.o ensem_hooks.o
ADJOINT = 

ifeq ($(ENSEM),TRUE)
MAIN = ensemble.f
HEADER = header header_ensem
COMPILER = mpif90
ENSEM_HOOKS = ensem_hooks.f
endif

ifeq ($(BATCH),TRUE)
MAIN = batch.f
HEADER = header header_batch
BATCH_HOOKS = batch_hooks.f
#ADJOINT = adj_chan.o adj_per.o
ADJOINT = adj_per.o
endif

# Use the parameters to set flags
ifeq ($(NETCDF),TRUE)
COMPOPTS = $(USEROPTS) $(HDF5OPTS) $(NEWTONOPTS) $(INCLUDEDIR)
LINKOPTS = $(LINKDIR) -ldrfftw -ldfftw -lnetcdf
NETCDF_o = netcdf.o
else
COMPOPTS = $(USEROPTS) $(HDF5OPTS) $(NEWTONOPTS)
LINKOPTS = $(LINKDIR) -lrfftw -lfftw \
    ./lib/liblapack_ifort64.a \
    ./lib/libblas_ifort64.a
NETCDF_o = no_netcdf.o
endif



diablo: $(MAIN) diablo_io.o channel.o $(LES_o) \
    fft.o newton.o shared.o solvers.o $(MPI) \
    $(HDF5_o)
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPOPTS) $(MAIN) -o diablo \
    diablo_io.o channel.o $(LES_o) \
    fft.o newton.o shared.o solvers.o \
    $(MPI) $(LINKOPTS) $(HDF5_o)

shared.o: shared.F grid_def grid_mpi
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPOPTS) -c shared.F

solvers.o: solvers.F shared.o grid_def grid_mpi
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPOPTS) -c solvers.F

diablo_io.o: diablo_io.F shared.o channel.o solvers.o fft.o $(HDF5_o)
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPOPTS) -c diablo_io.F

channel.o: channel.F solvers.o fft.o $(MPI) shared.o $(LES_o) grid_def grid_mpi
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPOPTS) -c channel.F

ifeq ($(LES),TRUE) 
les.o: les.F fft.o shared.o $(MPI) $(HDF5_o) grid_def grid_mpi
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPOPTS) -c les.F
else
no_les.o: dummy_code/no_les.f fft.o shared.o $(MPI) $(HDF5_o) grid_def grid_mpi
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPOPTS) -c dummy_code/no_les.f
endif

ifeq ($(NETCDF),TRUE)
netcdf.o: netcdf.f header
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPOPTS) -c netcdf.f
else
no_netcdf.o: dummy_code/no_netcdf.f 
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPOPTS) -c dummy_code/no_netcdf.f
endif

ifeq ($(PARALLEL),TRUE)
mpi.o: $(MPIF) shared.o solvers.o grid_def grid_mpi
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPOPTS) -c -o mpi.o $(MPIF) 
else
mpi_serial.o: dummy_code/mpi_serial.f shared.o solvers.o grid_def grid_mpi
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPOPTS) -c dummy_code/mpi_serial.f
endif

header : header_mpi grid_def

header_mpi : grid_mpi

hdf5.o : hdf5.F shared.o fft.o $(MPI) grid_def grid_mpi
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPOPTS) -c hdf5.F

fft.o:  fft.F shared.o $(MPI) grid_def grid_mpi
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPOPTS) -c fft.F

#rand.o:  rand.f grid_def grid_mpi
#   $(COMPILER) $(COMPOPTS) -c rand.f

newton.o: newton.F90 $(LES_o) $(HDF5_o) $(MPI) fft.o shared.o solvers.o \
    diablo_io.o grid_def grid_mpi NewtonHook.o GMRESm.o
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPOPTS) -c newton.F90

NewtonHook.o: NewtonHook.F90 $(LES_o) $(HDF5_o) $(MPI) fft.o shared.o solvers.o \
    diablo_io.o grid_def grid_mpi GMRESm.o
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPOPTS) -c NewtonHook.F90

GMRESm.o: GMRESm.F90 $(LES_o) $(HDF5_o) $(MPI) fft.o shared.o solvers.o \
    diablo_io.o grid_def grid_mpi
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPOPTS) -c GMRESm.F90

clean:
    rm -f *.o fort.* *~ diablo core *.mod
```

What's going on?

Comment: `COURANT` is defined in a module which is using another module, but it's the module being used that is trying to call the subroutine? You have a cyclic dependency so please show clearly what you are trying to achieve so that we can advise how to remove that. Note that you don't try to use `channel_module` in `hdf5_module` (which would be cyclic) so we can't see why you would expect that subroutine to be found. Please also see [mre].

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is compilation. As far as I see, there shouldn't be any problem in calling COURANT (defined in channel.f) in hdf5.f, should there be? I don't understand why the reference is undefined.

Comment: `courant` is defined in the module `channel_module`, but `hdf5_module` (/`ReadHDF5`) doesn't use that module. The one in the module isn't accessible, so unless you define another `courant` an undefined reference is likely. In the same way that if you don't `use hdf5_module` you can't call the subroutine `ReadHDF5` that module provides.

Answer (score 0):

`COURANT` is defined in `channel_module`.

So you need to `use channel_module` where it is needed in `hdf5_module` and not the other way around.

Right now your code has `use hdf5_module` in `channel_module`. Instead, try the following:

```
MODULE channel_module
  USE shared_module
  USE solvers_module
  USE les_module

  CONTAINS
  .....
  SUBROUTINE COURANT
  ..
  END SUBROUTINE COURANT
  .....
END MODULE channel_module
```

and

```
MODULE hdf5_module
  USE shared_module
  USE mpi_module
  USE channel_module

  CONTAINS 
  .....
  subroutine ReadHDF5
  ...
  CALL COURANT
  ...
  end subroutine ReadHDF5

END MODULE hdf5_module
```

Comment: It gives  "error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [CHANNEL_MODULE]", do I have to change the makefile as well?

Comment: Clear the build, and compile `channel_module` first.

Answer (score 0):

In short, this is a library linking ordering problem. A library is linked before another with symbols it depends on. It's quite a common beginner problem when compiling code, I've seen it quite a few times, and as such this is a good question, in my opinion. Certainly, it's one I found when searching for the error the user I was helping was seeing, so whether or not it's a duplicate seems beside the point (from a practical perspective: I can't speak for SO bylaws). This is particularly confusing when the two libraries are in the same package: I just saw this with someone linking against fftw2, but putting -l rfftw before -l fftw so their compilation failed with many "Undefined reference to ..." errors.

Comment: Why do you even argue about the duplicate beimg besides the point here? Tjere is no reasons for that. Also, being marked as a duplicate has nothing to do whether the question is good or not.

Comment: *"Certainly, it's one I found when searching for the error the user I was helping was seeing,"* That is the whole point keeping the duplicate questions as "sign posts" (yes, an established term on SE)  to lead to the one place where all the answers gather. One does not delete or downvote duplicates. And being marked as a duplicate does not mean that the question is bad. It only means that essentially the same thing has been asked before *and answered*. Nothing less, nothing more. Answerers are free to add new answers to the duplication target.

Comment: Note that the order of the libraries only matters for static archives.